# Using Razor to return strings in array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am taking an string[] from my Model and it has about 25ish strings in it at any given time.

```
@model PostProcessPartSelectionViewModel

@{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var part in Model.PartsAllowedAsSeed)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="[@i]" name="PartsAllowedAsSeed" value="@part" />
        <span>@part</span>
        <br />
        i++;
    }
}
```

I set up a @foreach loop in Razor to display a checkbox and label for each string, but when I debug, @part renders to System.Object[]. There are 25 checkboxes with 25 "System.Object[]" labels.

Eventually, I'm going to want to return any checked strings back to the model, but right now I just want to know how I can get Razor to render the actual string value.

Comment: The value of the items found in the `PartsAllowedAsSeed` property is an array of objects, so `"System.Object[]"` *is* the actual string value. What are you trying to do with the objects found in those arrays?

Comment: I should have specified this in the question, but the System.Object[] has strings inside it, but for my needs, I just need to encode each object as a single string.

Comment: So you're saying that the first `part` in `PartsAllowedAsSeed` would be something like `{"a", "b", "c"}`? In that case, what string do you want it to output in your `<span>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My case was pretty specific, so I don't think this will apply to anyone. I had a Object[] with objects in it and I wanted to display each child object as a string with Razor. I used a hack to cast the Object[] to a list, then append brackets to each list entry and reported each string back to Razor. For now, I don't need to bind directly to the model, so I opted to just use a foreach.

**Razor Code:**

```
@{
    var i = 0;
    @foreach (var item in Model.PartsAllowedAsSeed)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@i" name="PartsAllowedAsSeed" />
        <span>@Html.ConvertToArray(item)</span>
        <br />
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Helper Class:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString ConvertToArray(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object source)
        {
            var src = source as IEnumerable;

            if (src == null) return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Empty);

            var sourceAsList = src.Cast<Object>().ToList();

            var output = new StringBuilder();
            output.Append("[");
            for (var index = 0; index < sourceAsList.Count; index++)
            {
                var item = sourceAsList[index];
                output.Append(item);
                if (index != (sourceAsList.Count - 1)) output.Append(", ");
            }
            output.Append("]");

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(output.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `foreach` in razor, use a `for` loop so you can directly bind to your model:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.PartsAllowedAsSeed.Length; i++)
{
    <input type="checkbox" id="[@i]" name="PartsAllowedAsSeed" />
    <span> @Model.PartsAllowedAsSeed[i] </span>
    <br />
}
```

as for your `System.Object[]`, you can do `string.Join(", ", @Model.PartsAllowedAsSeed[i])` or some equivalent to meet your needs

Comment: I think that in the long run, it is much better for me to use a for instead of a foreach. However, I don't think that string.Join is going to do the trick for me, as it still returns System.Object[].